# LG L90 glass digitizer replacement doesn't work. The old one works

Tags: touchscreen, lg

My glass screen in LG L90 (d405 or d405n, i don't think there's a difference other than NFC) broke.

Bought a new glass screen with digitizer for d405. It looks exactly the same as the old one (hence I know it should be compatible).

1. I've replaced it. Touch didn't work. The old one (broken one) works.
2. I've sent it back because I thought it's damaged, they've sent me back a new one. Still didn't work (the old one still works).
3. I've bought a new one from a different vendor... still doesn't work. The old one still works.

what could be the problem here ? What should I do ?

Comment: This is pretty much impossible to answer, we can't know what you're doing wrong or what's wrong with the part.

Comment: Well I already answered myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that there were different versions of firmware for the screen: rev01 and rev02. I had the wrong one.